# Dynamic Content In Fancybox Not Working

Tags: custom-fields, javascript, jquery

I have a listing of staff member that I want to have a link that pops up a bio via fancybox. I have no problem getting this to work using static id's, but when I try to do it dynamically via a custom field it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<a class="staffLink" href="#" title="View {staff:staffName}'s bio">bio</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            $(".staffLink").fancybox({
                                                href        : '#{staff:staffName} Bio',
                                                maxWidth    : 800,
                                                maxHeight   : 600,
                                                fitToView   : false,
                                                width       : '70%',
                                                height      : '70%',
                                                autoSize    : false,
                                                closeClick  : false,
                                                openEffect  : 'none',
                                                closeEffect : 'none',
                                                helpers     : {
                                                    media : {},
                                                    title : null,
                                                    overlay: {
                                                        opacity: 0.9
                                                    } // overlay 
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>

<div style="display:none;" id="{staff:staffName} Bio">{staff:staffName} test content</div>
```

If I take out the custom field (staff:staffName) and just leave "Bio" for the id of the popup and in the the href of the Fancybox parameters it works. Also, If I look at the outputted code it populates correctly. The staff name is filled in for the href and the id.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's rendered to the browser? Sometimes EE parser can get confused on what's an EE variable and what's JS code. Please supply an example of the actual output. If EE isn't rendering the variable - place a JS variable being set outside of the JQuery e.g. var staffName = "{staff:staffName}"; and then refer to this JS variable in the JQuery code.

Comment: http://metooplace.com/about and select "DCC Team". The "bio" link is what we are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems, all related to JavaScript, not EE though. You'd be better off asking on the [general Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) if this doesn't answer it.

Your JavaScript code is being generated per loop of the bios, so you have 11 copies of the JS you've posted above and only the last one will ever run as they're all triggered from the same class trigger (.staffLink).

Next issue is your html is invalid - the ID you're trying to use the content for is invalid and has spacing in href: `'#Steve Eller Bio'`.

I'd suggest you ditch referencing it in that way and include only 1 occurance of the JS after all the bios have been output, then target the content relatively:

```
{START EE BIO LOOP}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 staffItem item active">
    <a class="staffLink" href="#" title="View {staff:staffName}'s bio">bio</a>
    ...
    <div style="display:none;" class="staffBio">{staff:staffName} test content</div>
</div>
{/END EE BIO LOOP}
```

Note that the Bio content for the popup is inside the staffItem div. Now the JS (note I've changed the href parameter to `content`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".staffLink").fancybox({
            content     : $(this).parent().siblings('.staffBio').html(),
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers     : {
                media : {},
                title : null,
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.9
                } // overlay 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately I am getting the same result.

Comment: Sorry missed .parent() from the content target - have amended answer - try that. You've also got a JS error referencing a missing function: multilevelpushmenu, although that's not effecting the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that other error.  Haven't fixed it yet.  Let me try your fix.  Thanks!

Comment: I finally got around to trying this but it still didn't fix it. I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Hi Steve, it works fine when you manually paste the code into the console (modifying the FancyBox trigger to $.fancybox.open({... and content: $(".staffLink").parent().sib...), so my guess is that you have Jquery loading after the above code and therefore it's not firing correct. The docs state load Jquery then add your fancybox code. Try moving the Fancybox JS library inclusion from your head to after JQuery library loading in the footer.